# Serializing pre-processing steps in weka

Tags: weka

I've been using the Weka GUI (the explorer in 3.7.11 specifically) to train some models. I then save the trained model by right-clicking on the model in the results pane. I've written some simple Java code that can load that saved model and use it to classify new instances. This all works great.

Naturally, I'd like to do some pre-processing to my data before training the model. Some of the pre-processing steps learn values. For example, the missing values filter learns the mean or mode of each feature from the training data. I would therefore like to save the learned filters just like I saved the learned model so I can apply the filters and then the model to new instances that weren't available when I trained my model. I can't seem to find any way to serialize the filters. Can this be done? If not, any advice for a simple work-around?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use MultiFilter to apply more than one filter if that's you are looking for.